# Having a bit of trouble getting a remote view to update text

Tags: android, widget

So after fighting with this for the last three hours I decided it was best to come here again.
I have this program set up that I want the user to be able to input something on one screen and it show up on the widget for that app. So far its not working out to well.

Here is some code:

```
case R.id.svbtn1:
        String nameData = inName1.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor4 = prefs.edit();
        prefs.edit().putString(constants.menuname1, nameData).commit();
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(),     R.layout.MyWidget);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.menubtn1, constants.menuName1);
        break;
```

So how do I get this to work when the svbtn1 is pressed?